# Faster mental calculations

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

Currently I am preparing for trading exams which tests faster arithmetic skills. For ex- 80 questions (like calculating 0.abc* 0.cd) to be done in 8 minutes.

I am trying to memorize the squares and tables and using simple tricks to solve these but still I am able to reach up-to 40 questions.

Any suggestions on how to increase my speed for such calculations. Any books or links are appreciated.

Comment: What examples do you struggle on? you say you can do 40 in 8 minutes, so what slows you down?

Comment: Those which involve fractions. Its mainly the problems involving decimal  that I struggle with.

Comment: The decimal is no problem. Just multiplicate and shift the comma to the left. Just count the decimals after the commata to see how far you have to shift.

Comment: @Peter not all questions were of multiplications. It included addition and subtraction too

Comment: @uzumaki Do you visit a special school for those interested in mental-arithmetic ?

Comment: @Peter: Nitpick: $10$ questions per minute, so $6$ seconds per multiplication. :)

Comment: @Peter No, I am just trying to memorize tables and trying to look for faster tricks currently

Comment: Are these more or less random digits you're calculating?  Any patterns like multiplying by $0.25$, $0.125$, etc.?

Comment: @John you are right. I must have mixed something. So or so, I have failed :)

Comment: Reddit has a [mental math subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mentalmath/)  that could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how much time you have to prepare, it is hard to beat Arthur Benjamin's [*Secrets of Mental Math*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307338401). The Contents in case you are interested and to see whether or not you think it may meet your needs:

1. Mental Addition and Subtraction
2. Basic Multiplication
3. Intermediate Multiplication
4. Mental Division
5. The Art of "Guesstimation"
6. Pencil-and-Paper Math
7. Memorizing Numbers
8. Advanced Multiplication
9. The Art of Mathematical Magic

Manipulation of decimals and the like occurs in chapter 4 on mental division. Personally, I have only worked through the first few chapters, but I was surprised at how effective everything he puts forth is.

Comment: Thanks, I would give it a try then

Comment: Keep in mind that it is a *book* even though a small and simple one. Mastering the techniques Art puts forth will take a fair amount of time.